# Manually hitting a SOAP Service in Java, getting IO.FileNotFound exception

Tags: java, soap, filenotfoundexception, manual

I need to access a .Net SOAP Service manually. All the importers have issues with its WSDL, so I'm just manually creating the XML message, using HttpURLConnection to connect, and then parsing the results. I've wrapped the Http/SOAP call into a function that is supposed to return the results as a string. Here's what I have:

```
  //passed in values: urlAddress, soapAction, soapDocument

  URL u = new URL(urlAddress);
  URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uc;

  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setDoInput(true);
  connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
  connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction);
  connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","[star]/[star]");      
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

  OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
  Writer wout = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

  //helper function that gets a string from a dom Document
  String xmldata = XmlUtils.GetDocumentXml(soapDocument);
  wout.write(xmldata);        
  wout.flush();
  wout.close();

  // Response
  int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
  String responseString = "";
  String outputString = "";
  //Write the SOAP message response to a String.
  while ((responseString = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      outputString = outputString + responseString;
  }

  return outputString;
```

My problem is on the line `BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));` I get a "java.io.FileNotFoundException" with the address that I'm using (i.e. urlAddress). If I paste that address into a browser, it pulls up the Soap Service webpage just fine (address is http://protectpaytest.propay.com/API/SPS.svc). From what I've read, the FileNotFoundException is if the HttpURLConnection returns a 400+ error message. I added the line getResponseCode() just to see what the exact code was, and it's 404. I added the User-Agent and Accept headers from some other pages saying they were needed, but I'm still getting 404.

Are there other headers I'm missing? What else do I need to do to get this call to work (since it works in a browser)?

-shnar

Comment: Did you try using something like SoapUI ?

Comment: SoapUI? I tried wsdl2java and jaxb, neither worked so I gave up and tried just manually hitting via http, but I'm having problems with that now (as described above)...

Comment: An update: I added in a call to connection.getErrorStream() but this is returning null. So even though I'm getting a 404, I'm also getting no error. Is that what this is supposed to do?

Comment: Another update: I thought maybe my Soap message was invalid, so I pasted the message into wsdlbrowser.com and executed it there, and it worked fine. Why can't I get my HttpURLConnection to work?!?

Comment: Final update, after using wsdlebrowser.com and fiddler, I figured out my problem was that I was posting to HTTP (the same as the WSDL) but it was failing. Once I posted to HTTPS, it worked fine.